# Connection error in Sequelize,Postgres,Nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, stack-overflow

LOG:
///////////////

```
            reject(new sequelizeErrors.ConnectionError(err));
                   ^
```

ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
at Client._connectionCallback (/home/rishikesh/Desktop/Bug_tracker_test_1/Bug_Tracker_TOOL/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:142:24)
at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/home/rishikesh/Desktop/Bug_tracker_test_1/Bug_Tracker_TOOL/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
at Client._handleErrorMessage (/home/rishikesh/Desktop/Bug_tracker_test_1/Bug_Tracker_TOOL/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:325:19)
at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
at /home/rishikesh/Desktop/Bug_tracker_test_1/Bug_Tracker_TOOL/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:114:12
at Parser.parse (/home/rishikesh/Desktop/Bug_tracker_test_1/Bug_Tracker_TOOL/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17)
at Socket. (/home/rishikesh/Desktop/Bug_tracker_test_1/Bug_Tracker_TOOL/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9) {
parent: error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/rishikesh/Desktop/Bug_tracker_test_1/Bug_Tracker_TOOL/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
at Parser.handlePacket (/home/rishikesh/Desktop/Bug_tracker_test_1/Bug_Tracker_TOOL/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
at Parser.parse (/home/rishikesh/Desktop/Bug_tracker_test_1/Bug_Tracker_TOOL/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
at Socket. (/home/rishikesh/Desktop/Bug_tracker_test_1/Bug_Tracker_TOOL/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {

///////////////sequelize

const {Sequelize,DataTypes} = require('sequelize');

const Upload_Model = require('./excel_upload_model');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('BugTracker','postgres','',{
host:'localhost',
dialect:'postgres'
});

const Sequelize_model = Upload_Model(sequelize,Sequelize);

sequelize.sync()
.then(()=>{
console.log(`Database is ready`)
})

module.exports = {
Sequelize_model
}

///////////// models

module.exports=(sequelize,DataTypes)=>{

```
return sequelize.define('excel_upload_model',{

    id:{
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        required:true,
        primaryKey: true
    },

    unique_name:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
    },
enter code here
    filename:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
    }

})
```

}

Comment: i have checked with the password In case if u guys are wondering

Comment: Yes, you showed us the log of the check with the password, and the check failed.  Did you check in a different way and have it succeed?  If so, show us that too.

Comment: Do you really have an empty password?

Comment: @jjanes can u explain more about different ways bacause i am very new to sequelize concepts

Comment: @Anatoly  No it just copy-pasting mistake :)

Comment: I don't know anything about sequelize,, I'm just reading the error message you got passed back from PostgreSQL.  You could try to log on without something simpler, like `psql` and see if that succeeds.